# Converting vertex colors to UV texture in meshlab

Tags: graphics, 3d, blender, meshlab

I am trying to write a script that converts the vertex colors of a scanned .ply model to a good UV texture map so that it can be 3D painted as well as re-sculpted in another program like Mudbox.

Right now I am unwrapping the model using smart projection in Blender, and then using Meshlab to convert the vertex colors to a texture. My approach is mostly working, and at first the texture seems to be converted with no issues, but when I try to use the smooth brush in Mudbox/Blender to smooth out some areas of the model after the texture conversion, small polygons rise to the surface that are untextured. Here is an image of the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmekzxvvi44umce/Image.png?dl=0

All of these small polygons seem to have their own UV shells separate from the rest of the mesh, they all seem to be invisible from the surface of the model before smoothing, and they are difficult or impossible to repaint in Mudbox/Blender.

I tried baking the texture in Blender as well but experienced similar problems. I'm pretty stumped so any solutions or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Doing some basic mesh cleanup in Meshlab (merging close vertices in particular) seems to have mostly solved the problem.